# The "other" ideal quotient generalized to modules

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

If I'm not mistaken, given a commutative ring $A$, an ideal $R$ and a family of submodules $(M_i)_{i\in I}$ of an $A$-module $X$, we have:

$$R \cdot \left(\sum_{i\in I} M_i\right) = \sum_{i\in I} R\cdot M_i.$$

That implies the function $R\cdot \_ : \operatorname{Sub} X\to \operatorname{Sub} X$, where $\operatorname{Sub} X$ is the poset of submodules of $X$, has a right-adjoint $\_ : R$ given by :

$$M : R = \sum \{ N\in \operatorname{Sub} X : R\cdot N \leq M\}$$

Of course if $X = A$, then this reduces to the familiar "ideal quotient".

> Does this have an established name and 
>   a simpler description?

This should not be confused with the well-known "quotient" of a module by another module:

$$M : N = \{a\in A : aN\subseteq M\}$$

In fact, $\_ : N$ right-adjoint to $\_ \cdot N$ and here $N$ is a submodule and $M : N$ is an ideal. In the above "division" the reverse is true.

Comment: The set of indices is the ideal???

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, my mistake. Of course it is not.